# Using Selenium, TestNG and ReportNG with Gradle

Tags: testng, gradle, reportng

Has anybody here successfully configured reportng with gradle 1.0-milestone-9?

I downloaded a Selenium 2, TestNG sample developed with Gradle (from https://github.com/iainrose/page-objects).  It works nicely (after adding System Properties to build.gradle for switching browsers) and now I would like to add ReportNG to the mix.  I tried the following:

```
dependencies {
compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.15.0"
compile "org.testng:testng:6.3.1"
compile "org.uncommons:reportng:1.1.2"
}
```

It produces the following error:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Artifact 'org.testng:testng:6.3.1:jdk15@jar' not found.
```

I found a similar issue at http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2042 and added a comment there, however, there's been no follow up yet.  The only suggestion there is to remove reportng from dependencies...  I'm hoping someone here knows of a way to get reportng working with gradle.

**After adding code suggested by Szpak below:**

After adding code to build.gradle as suggested by Szpak I could finally run the tests - still without the reportng listeners but with the dependency in place.  However, once I plugged in listeners, as in:

```
    useTestNG() {
    options {
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
    }
```

I got java.lang.StackOverflowError:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'console-bg1'.
> java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'console-bg1'.
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)

(...)

Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:804)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1096)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1049)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGOptions.methodMissing(TestNGOptions.groovy:204)
```

From my research online it looks like something is wrong with the dependencies.  I am still unable to use reportng with gradle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you can exclude testng-5.0-jdk15 transitive dependency from reportng package.

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.15.0"
    compile "org.testng:testng:6.3.1"
    compile("org.uncommons:reportng:1.1.2") {
        exclude group: "org.testng", module: "testng"
    }
    compile "com.google.inject:guice:3.0"
}
```

Btw, testCompile usually is a better choice for test dependencies.

**Update**: Added guice dependency to avoid "ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.Module".

Comment: This causes a lot of compilation errors, since neither selenium nor testng packages are found any more...

Comment: OK, I take that back - it was the changing from compile to testCompile that started throwing all the compilation errors.  Once I want back to compile, your code worked just fine - I no longer get the dreaded 'Artifact not found error'.  The tests executed.  Thank you!

Comment: After adding reportng listeners build fails with the java.lang.StackOverflowError exception.  From my search it looks like this could be related to dependencies (see http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/StackOverflowError-in-idea-plugin-td3207809.html).  I cannot determine if this is an issue with gradle or something wrong in dependency declaration.  I'll part of the exception to the original post.

Comment: Hmm, updated TestNG to 6.3.1 on my project which has configured ReportNG and it works fine (I had to add guice as a dependency to prevent "ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.Module" after test execution). Could check ReportNG with some simple tests first (without Selenium)? Btw, which version of Gradle are you using? I tested it with 1.0-milestone-9. Btw2, it shouldn't be a problem, but you can also disable default listeners (useDefaultListeners = false).

Comment: I moved to gradle 1.0-rc-3 (from 1.0-milestone-9) but the result is the same: StackOverflow exception when using reportng listeners.  Logged this issue in jira under [link]http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2246?jwupdated=65633&focusedCommentId=15483

Comment: I created a simple TestNG only project and tested it.  All worked fine, then I added ReportNG listeners and this time got different exception Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/Module.  Not sure this relates to the original issue.  More details and the project itself at [link](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2246?jwupdated=64379&focusedCommentId=15548#comment-15548).  Can anybody help?

Comment: Adding guice to dependencies fixed the problem in both projects:

Comment: Here is the code: compile group: 'com.google.inject', name: 'guice', version: '3.0'

Comment: Btw, in my first comment I mentioned that "I had to add guice as a dependency to prevent "ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.Module" after test execution".

Comment: I missed that part of your comment...  Please add the guice code to your answer and I'll mark it as correct one.

Comment: I just added it. Btw, I suspect that you have the same problem with missed notifications as I had :).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked, including Szpak's contribution:

```
dependencies {
compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.21.0"
compile "org.testng:testng:6.3.1"
compile group: 'com.google.inject', name: 'guice', version: '3.0'
compile("org.uncommons:reportng:1.1.2") {
    exclude group: "org.testng", module: "testng"
    }
}
```